# Synchronous cross-domain ajax DELETE request on unload

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, browser

I am working with cross-domain remote resources that require locking.  CORs headers are set appropriately.

I am trying to solve the case where the resource is not released by the client (remains locked until the lock expires) when the browser window is closed.

I had hoped to send a synchronous DELETE request on window unload.  I am using jquery (answer can be plain javascript if necessary... mentioning jquery for context) and noticed their docs say "Cross-domain requests ... do not support synchronous operation" and I became very sad.

Is it possible to make a synchronous cross-domain ajax request?  Is the jquery limitation due to older browsers?  Everything I've read indicates the unload event listener will not be around long enough for the ajax call to complete if it is async and suggests using a synchronous request for this type of cleanup.  Unfortunately the call is cross-domain...  what can I do?

---

### EDIT

---

So I am curious if I am getting lucky during local development (i.e. client on 127.0.0.1:8080 and api on 127.0.0.1:8081) or the jquery docs are just misleading.  Will the following end up causing me problems down the road?

This appears to be working in Chrome45:

```
var unload_event = "unload." + lock.id

function release_lock(sync) {
    $.ajax({
        method: "DELETE",
        async: !sync,
        data: lock,
        url: lock.url,
        error: function(){
            console.log("failed to release lock " + JSON.stringify(lock));
        },
        success: function(){
            console.log("lock " + lock.id + " released");
            lock = null;
            $(window).off(unload_event);
        }
    });
}

$(window).on(unload_event, function(){
    release_lock(true);
});
```

It does generate the following warning in the console:

```
Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of
its detrimental effects to the end user's experience.
For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.
```

Comment: Handle the locking by some other means than an unload event, such as keepalive polling and a timeout; If no keepalive request is made within a certain time period, assume the client has closed the page and unlock it.

Comment: @KevinB I do that already but I would like them to be immediately available instead of waiting for the lock to expire.  Going to update the original post with a comment.  I might just be getting lucky in chrome but it seems to be allowing the request.

Comment: Websockets would be another option if the backend supported it. Synchronous requests on unload just feels hacky to me.

Comment: As far as the jquery docs about sync and cross-domain, i would ignore that, as there is no such restriction on XmlHttpRequest documentation. sync requests in general are of course deprecated though. That note may be there due to some older browser not supporting synchronous CORS requests.

Comment: This is due to this: async: !sync, why not always use asynchronous? Synchronous can hang the browser until response is given...

Comment: @LucLaverdure I covered that in the question.  The synchronous flag is on purpose

Comment: @KevinB if you want to write your comments into an answer and possibly explain the websokets comment (do you just mean faster polling over the websocket since there isn't a connection overhead?) I'll accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would avoid doing this in the unload event due to the fact that synchronous ajax is the only way that will work, and synchronous ajax requests are deprecated in some modern browsers.

Alternatives include:

#### keepalive requests

This would involve periodically sending a request to the server indicating that the user is still editing the resource. The downside to this technique is that the resource will remain locked until the timeout happens, so if you're keepalive is set to an interval of 1 minute with a 3 minute lock timeout, it will remain locked for up to 3 minutes after the user has left the page. Additionally, if the user loses network connection for 3 minutes or longer, it will also become unlocked.

#### websockets

This would create an open connection between the client and the server, and while this connection is open, you can keep the resource locked. As soon as the client disconnects, you can assume that the client has closed the page and unlock it. The downside here is if the client loses network connection, it will also become unlocked.